# How to change the image format from JPEG to PNG in android?

Tags: android, camera, png

I am opening the default android device camera by passing an intent. So when an image is captured, by default, camera stores it in JPEG format. But I don't want to store them in lossy format. I want picture quality to be high. So how can i store it in PNG format?...

here goes my code to open camera :

```
Date dt = new Date();     
        int date=dt.getDate();  
        int hours = dt.getHours();     
        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();   
        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();     
        String curTime = date+"_"+hours + "_"+minutes + "_"+ seconds;  
         _path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+curTime+".jpg";  
        File file = new File( _path );  
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );  
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );  
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );  

 context.startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Then handle onActivutyForResult (){....}

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Just because it's JPEG doesn't mean the quality will be bad...the image taken by the camera will be a high resolution (default settings) and usually weighs 500kB-2MB.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I haven't come across any method to make the camera save the file as `PNG`.

But you could convert the `JPEG` Image into `PNG` format.

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); //100-best quality
       out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note, this won't enhance the quality. You cannot "increase" the information in an image. This will only change the Image Format.

Comment: Is there any image compression technique in android so that I can get high quality image and store it in my sdcard and send it to server?

Comment: @Sneha, If you strictly need the high res images, don't use any compression...just send the file the camera intent provides...that's the best you'll get.

Comment: @st0le .. is size will decrease after convert type to png

Comment: @st0le According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), the compression quality parameter will be ignored by lossless formats, such as PNG.