# Taking pictures in RAW or PNG format without Intent

Tags: android

I am currently making an app that require pictures of high quality. Because of this I would like to take pictures in .PNG format but I only figured out how to do this in JPEG so far. I use the following method take_picture() for this. This method includes the following line to get hold of expected picture size:

```
jpegSizes = camera_characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

And then creating an ImageReader for capturing the picture:

```
ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
```

Is there any way to use .PNG here instead? ImageFormat does not seem to support .PNG. All answers are much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474032/how-to-change-the-image-format-from-jpeg-to-png-in-android
check this out.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I was trying to avoid using Mediastores Intent if possible